# how can i use indexPath.Autorelease ? removing last index value

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios, release, autorelease

i am develop with monotouch and uitableview remembers last selections so i need to release it                           indexPath.IndexPathByRemovingLastIndex (); usage, is there any way at row selection?

Comment: Your question is not clear but I think what you really want is deselectRowAtIndexPath (http://iosapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=M%3AMonoTouch.UIKit.UITableView.DeselectRow).

Answer (score 0):

Do you want delete Selected Row ? If yes.

```
RemoveObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row);
```